# Javascript function not invoked on calling

Tags: javascript

I was implementing a LiveCart updating method using JavaScript that calculates the total amount. But the JavaScript function is not being invoked. It was working before using Django variables as HTML values. But now even after removing them the function is not being invoked.

```js
function display() {
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  var fd = document.getElementById("search-input-in").value;
  var sd = document.getElementById("search-input-out").value;
  var firstDate = new Date(fd);
  var secondDate = new Date(sd);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
  var ind = document.getElementById("search-input-min").value;
  var base = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  var button = document.getElementById("search-button");
  if (base == "Cottage and Food"
    or "Cottage") {
    base = 2000;
  }
  if (base == "Other") {
    base = 1500;
  }
  if (diffDays == 0) {
    diffDays = 1;
  }
  num = base * ind * diffDays;
  str1 = "Pay Rs.";
  str2 = num.toString();
  res = str1.concat(str2);
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    button.value = "Pay Rs.0";
    alert(".........");
  } else {
    button.value = res;
    return num;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-div">
  <form class="form-control" action="#" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/livecart.js' %}">
      display();
    </script>
    <h1 id="search-text">\ Checkout \</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <label class="search-input" for="select-package">Package </label><br>
    <select required id="search-input" name="package-type">
      <option class="search-input" value={{package}}>{{package}}</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label class="search-input" for="in-date">Check-in date </label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-in" type="date" name="in-date" value={{inDate}}><br>
    <label class="search-input" for="out-date">Check-out date </label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-out" type="date" name="out-date" value={{outDate}}><br>
    <label class="search-input" for="indiviuals">Indiviuals</label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-min" type="number" name="individuals" value="0" onchange="display();"><br>
    <hr>
    <input id="search-button" type="submit" name="search" value="Pay Rs.0">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (base == "Cottage and Food" or "Cottage")`: this is not like this that you do a "or" in Javascript, that should be `if (base == "Cottage and Food" || base == "Cottage")`

Answer (score 0):

According to this [tutorial](https://javascript.info/hello-world).

> If `src` is set, the script content is ignored.

So try this:

```
 <script src="{% static 'js/livecart.js' %}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   display();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in the JavaScript code in the `if` condition `(base == "Cottage and Food" or "Cottage")`. Replace it with `(base == "Cottage and Food" || base == "Cottage")`.

See the code below.

```js
function display() {
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  var fd = document.getElementById("search-input-in").value;
  var sd = document.getElementById("search-input-out").value;
  var firstDate = new Date(fd);
  var secondDate = new Date(sd);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
  var ind = document.getElementById("search-input-min").value;
  var base = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  var button = document.getElementById("search-button");
  if (base == "Cottage and Food" ||
    base == "Cottage") {
    base = 2000;
  }
  if (base == "Other") {
    base = 1500;
  }
  if (diffDays == 0) {
    diffDays = 1;
  }
  num = base * ind * diffDays;
  str1 = "Pay Rs.";
  str2 = num.toString();
  res = str1.concat(str2);
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    button.value = "Pay Rs.0";
    alert(".........");
  } else {
    button.value = res;
    return num;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-div">
  <form class="form-control" action="#" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/livecart.js' %}">
      display();
    </script>
    <h1 id="search-text">\ Checkout \</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <label class="search-input" for="select-package">Package </label><br>
    <select required id="search-input" name="package-type">
      <option class="search-input" value={{package}}>{{package}}</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label class="search-input" for="in-date">Check-in date </label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-in" type="date" name="in-date" value={{inDate}}><br>
    <label class="search-input" for="out-date">Check-out date </label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-out" type="date" name="out-date" value={{outDate}}><br>
    <label class="search-input" for="indiviuals">Indiviuals</label><br>
    <input required id="search-input-min" type="number" name="individuals" value="0" onchange="display();"><br>
    <hr>
    <input id="search-button" type="submit" name="search" value="Pay Rs.0">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: still  not resolved. It has to do something with the django fucntion i think.. because  the code works in the snipplet but not in project